# cleaning up db of redundant data

Tags: php, mysql

```
locid   country city
39409   US  Aaronsburg
128426  US  Aaronsburg
340356  US  Aaronsburg
429373  US  Aaronsburg
422717  US  Abbeville
431344  US  Abbeville
433062  US  Abbeville
341726  US  Abbeville
421248  US  Abbeville
40779   US  Abbeville
326718  US  Abbeville
317654  US  Abbeville
16707   US  Abbeville
25771   US  Abbeville
120301  US  Abbeville
132115  US  Abbeville
121770  US  Abbeville
130397  US  Abbeville
5585    US  Abbeville
10227   US  Abbeville
190173  US  Abbeville
491120  US  Abbeville
311174  US  Abbeville
306532  US  Abbeville
164271  US  Abbot
465218  US  Abbot
58452   US  Abbotsford
359399  US  Abbotsford
309116  US  Abbotsford
8169    US  Abbotsford
```

can someone give me an sql query to help me clean up this table?
after clean up locid(the index) should be resetted, btw this is a county city using this query ***`SELECT locid, country, city FROM location WHERE country =  'US' ORDER BY city ASC`*** . this redundant data came about when i imported an sql text many times  through phpmyadmin's import and this is the result,

Comment: export the data uniquely and then re-imoprt?

Comment: my phpmyadmin's export doesnt have that, it only exports as is. probably another sql statement should fix it

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add unique index on table location so that no duplicate records will get inserted

```
ALTER IGNORE TABLE location ADD UNIQUE KEY ix1(country, city);
```

This will automatically remove duplicate records from the table and for future insert queries you need to use `INSERT IGNORE` clause to avoid getting duplicate errors.

but as suggested by `@AD7six` in comments, it might not work on MySQL versions `5.1.41,5.5.1-m2, 6.0`: see bug [here](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=40344)

or alternate safe way to remove duplicates using `DELETE` query:

```
DELETE a
FROM location a
     LEFT JOIN (
                SELECT locid
                FROM location
                GROUP BY country, city
               )b
               ON a.locid = b.locid
WHERE b.locid IS NULL;
```

to resettle values of `auto_increment` column `locid`, you can just drop the `primary key` on `locid` and recreate it:

```
ALTER TABLE location DROP column locid;
ALTER TABLE location 
      ADD COLUMN locid INT unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY FIRST;
```

or alternative way to resettle values of `locid` using `UPDATE` query:

```
SET var_locid = 0;

UPDATE location
SET locid = (@var_locid := @var_locid + 1)
ORDER BY locid ASC;
```

Comment: you can add multiple unique indexes on same table. to resettle locid(the index). you can drop primary key on locid and recreate it.

Comment: if you for some reasons want new lower locid, drop that field and add a new auto_increment field

Comment: ok so i dropped my locid and recreated one, well at least the numbering is reset, so i would have to accept this as my answer

Comment: It transpires that, depending on the version used, mysql does not do what you'd expect with the above - [the ignore flag isn't honored](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=40344)

Comment: @AD7six: Thanks for pointing out this issue. I have updated my answer accordingly. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 4):

You can do this in several - each simple - steps.

#### Backup your original table

If you haven't already - back up your original table data.

#### Create a temporary table

Create a new table, which you are going to use to replace your original table. Here's an example:

```
CREATE TABLE temporary (
  locid INTEGER(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  country VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT '',
  city VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT '',
  PRIMARY KEY  (locid),
  UNIQUE KEY  (country, city)
);
```

The schema should be almost the same as your existing table the note-worthy differences are:

- Auto increment primary key
- A unique country+city index

#### Import your old data

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO temporary (country, city) SELECT country, city FROM original_table_name;
```

This will populate your temporary table with unique country+city combinations. Each row will be assigned an auto-increment value - i.e. it will start with 1.

#### Check results

Have a look at your data and make sure it looks like you want it:

```
SELECT * FROM temporary;
```

If anything is amiss - drop the table `temporary` adjust the sql you are running and start again.

#### Replace your original table with your new one

Once you are happy with what you see in your `temporary` table:

```
DROP TABLE original_table_name; -- Or rename it to something else
RENAME TABLE temporary TO original_table_name;
```

You now have a table with unique data and sequential ids starting with 1.

#### Other options

You can also just apply a unique index to country+city, drop the primary key field, and then re-add it as an autoincrement. Be aware that **[mysql may ignore the ignore flag when creating indexes](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=40344)**, though there's a [workaround for that](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12029761/761202).

I'd do that personally, but if you're not confident with sql - doing things one step at a time, and without destroying your source data in the process, can make updating your schema a less worrying task.

Comment: already tried @omesh answer since it was the simplest and shortest but thanks anyway

Comment: omesh's answer is fine, and I voted for it. Only criticism would be it doesn't (in the answer) address the primary key part of your question

Answer (score 1):

delete these recordds

```
select T2.* from ( 
     select country city,max(locid)locid
     from <table>
     group by country city)T1
     join
     select * from <table> T2
     where T2.locid<>T1.locid
```

Comment: by that you mean that i should create another table? T2 means the new table? whereas T1 is the old table?

Answer (score 0):

Create a new table with new auto_increment field and just select them with GROUP BY into the new table

Not tested but should look like this:

```
INSERT INTO new_table(country, city) 
SELECT country, city FROM old_table 
GROUP BY country,city
```

EDIT:
You could drop the old_table and rename the new_table afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

1. Select the unique records and insert into another temporary table of the same schema.
2. delete everyting from his table
3. Select and insert back in from the temporary table.
4. Remove temporary table