# MySQL Where Not Exists Insert Record based on 3 values

Tags: mysql, insert

I have a need to do an insert to MySQL where a record does not exist in the destination table already

my query

```
INSERT INTO comment (`mid`, `pid`, `comment_text`, `comment_date`, `comment_type`) 
 VALUES (180, 2, NULL, '2012-07-26 10:19:00', 'tag')  WHERE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT * FROM `comment` WHERE `mid`=180 AND `pid`=2 AND `comment_type`='tag')
```

however when this runs I get this error

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'WHERE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT * FROM `comment` WHERE `mid`=180 AND
>   `pid' at line 2

Any ideas essentially i want to stop duplicate rows being added to this table when they match the values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO comment
(
 `mid`, `pid`, `comment_text`, `comment_date`, `comment_type`
)
(
    SELECT 180, 2, NULL, '2012-07-26 10:19:00', 'tag'
    FROM comment
    WHERE `mid`=180 AND
          `pid`=2 AND
          `comment_type`='tag'
    LIMIT 1
);
```

EDIT: Better way to do this:

to remove duplicates from a table [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11557757/cleaning-up-db-of-redundant-data/11557812#11557812)

```
ALTER IGNORE TABLE comment ADD UNIQUE KEY ix1(mid, pid, comment_type);

INSERT IGNORE INTO comment
(
 `mid`, `pid`, `comment_text`, `comment_date`, `comment_type`
)
VALUES 
(
 SELECT 180, 2, NULL, '2012-07-26 10:19:00', 'tag'
);
```

Comment: Thanks but this is still adding a row

Answer (score 0):

add an `ignore`

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO comment ...
```

to prevent duplicate inserts. You can't use a `where` clause in an `insert`.

> If you use the IGNORE keyword, errors that occur while executing the INSERT statement are treated as warnings instead. For example, without IGNORE, a row that duplicates an existing UNIQUE index or PRIMARY KEY value in the table causes a duplicate-key error and the statement is aborted. With IGNORE, the row still is not inserted, but no error is issued.

Taken from [the MySQL INSERT Documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/insert.html)

That means you should add a unique key to your table (if you haven't already) to make the DB check for duplicates by itself. If the DB finds a duplicate no `INSERT` will be made.

if you want to make an `UPDATE` in case of duplicates that is possible too. See [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/insert-on-duplicate.html)

Comment: thanks for your reply could you expand on your answer a bit please thanks

Comment: thanks for that I do have a unique id which is not the field I am trying to prevent duplicates against, essentially there are 3 type of comments in this table 'text', 'tag', 'view' the user can add as many text comments as they want but only 1 tag and 1 view there are multiple users who can insert based on mid

Comment: To implement rather complicated conditions you could write a `before insert` trigger that checks that for you. [cancel-insert-example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/229765/)

Answer (score 0):

Why not just to make unique index that consists of mid, pid and comment_type columns?

Comment: Good suggestion but in this use case it won't work as I need other users to add a tag and also allow them to add other comment types