# issue with removing duplicates from a database without removing the original

Tags: mysql

Ive been stuck on this all day and finally found a script which would remove all data with the exception of the original, anyway, i done the necessary changes to allow it to work with my code, unfortunately it is spitting out an syntax error. Ive been looking at it for about 2 hours now and i just cant see it.
Anyway, im using the MySQL DB and heres the script im using..

```
DELETE * 
FROM music u
JOIN (

SELECT melody, chorus1, chorus2, MIN( id ) AS minid
FROM music
GROUP BY melody, chorus1, chorus2
HAVING (
COUNT( * ) >1
)
) AS dupusers ON u.melody = dupusers.melody
AND u.chorus1 = dupusers.chorus1
AND u.chorus2 = dupusers.chorus2
ORDER BY u.melody, u.chorus1, u.chorus2
WHERE u.id <> minid
```

and I get the following error:

> 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near '* FROM music u JOIN ( SELECT melody, chorus1, chorus2, MIN( id )
>   AS minid ' at line 1

which is..

```
* 
FROM music u
JOIN (

SELECT melody, chorus1, chorus2, MIN( id ) AS minid
```

Comment: `DELETE * FROM table` is not valid SQL. `DELETE FROM table` would be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

its because you have syntax error at `DELETE *`  and you have used `WHERE` clause after `ORDER BY` clause. no need to use `ORDER BY` clause in `DELETE` query without limit try:

```
DELETE u
FROM music u
    INNER JOIN (
        SELECT melody, chorus1, chorus2, MIN( id ) AS minid
        FROM music
        GROUP BY melody, chorus1, chorus2
        HAVING COUNT(*) >1
    ) dupusers
    ON u.melody = dupusers.melody
        AND u.chorus1 = dupusers.chorus1
        AND u.chorus2 = dupusers.chorus2
WHERE u.id <> minid;
```

another easy way to remove duplicates is to add unique index on table see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11557757/cleaning-up-db-of-redundant-data/11557812#11557812).

```
ALTER IGNORE TABLE music ADD UNIQUE KEY ix1(melody, chorus1, chorus2);
```